# pwd command with shell script

Tags: shell

I am calling a script as below

---

directory path  : /user/local/script/print_path.sh

```
var_path=`pwd`
echo $var_path
```

The above script is calling as below 
directory path  : /user/local/callPscript/call.sh

```
`/user/local/script/print_path.sh`
```

---

I want the out put as below :

```
/user/local/script/
```

But it gives the output :

```
/user/local/callPscript/
```

---

i.e. the pocation of the script is called. How can I make it to the scripts home directory path?

Comment: You're not new; you really ought to know how to format your questions by now. And how to accept answers.

Comment: I agree, with 13 questions already (and no accepted answers) you really should know how to format. I fixed it for you this time. Please put more effort in your questions.

Comment: Ok i will do here after ... Thanks

Comment: Why wait? You can go back and accept answers to your older questions, too.

Answer (score 7):

After some weeks of Bash programming, this has emerged as the standard solution:

```
directory=$(dirname -- $(readlink -fn -- "$0"))
```

`$0` is the relative path to the script, `readlink -f` resolves that into an absolute path, and `dirname` strips the script filename from the end of the path.

A safer variant based on the [completely safe find](https://gist.github.com/716763):

```
directoryx="$(dirname -- $(readlink -fn -- "$0"; echo x))"
directory="${directoryx%x}"
```

This should be safe with any filename - `$()` structures remove newlines at the end of the string, which is the reason for the `x` at the end.

Answer (score 3):

May be this can help you.

```
var_path=$PWD  
echo $var_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it should come close to what you want:

```
var_path=`dirname "$0"`
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [BashFAQ/028](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

> This topic comes up frequently. This answer covers not only the expression used above ("configuration files"), but also several variant situations. If you've been directed here, please read this entire answer before dismissing it.
>
> This is a complex question because there's no single right answer to it. Even worse: it's not possible to find the location reliably in 100% of all cases. All ways of finding a script's location depend on the name of the script, as seen in the predefined variable $0. But providing the script name in $0 is only a (very common) convention, not a requirement.
>
> . . .
>
> Generally, storing data files in the same directory as their programs is a bad practise. The Unix file system layout assumes that files in one place (e.g. /bin) are executable programs, while files in another place (e.g. /etc) are data files.

Read the complete page for lots more good information.